# EXCEL: Check if value in cell has more than one value under it in adjacent row

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vlookup

Sorry, I tried my best to frame my question in the title! But here's what I'm trying to do:

I have an excel sheet of two columns, `A` and `B`. I am trying to check if a value underneath `A` has two or more values underneath it in `B`. See below:

```
A               B
France          Paris
France          Paris
France          Nice
California      Los Angeles
California      Los Angeles
Japan           Tokyo
Japan           Tokyo
```

In here, I am trying to report back that `France` is a value in column `A` that has more than one value in `B` (`Paris` and `Nice`). How do I write a comparison formula in Excel that will allow me to do this?

I thought about doing something along the lines of doing `VLOOKUP` to report back the first row (`France` --> `Paris`, `California` --> `Los Angeles`, `Japan` --> `Tokyo`), and if the value in `B` does not equal the value in the first row, report that back to me.

Ex.
in `C4`, it's supposed to anticipate `Paris` but a conditional will throw `False` since it's equal to `Nice`.

TIA!

Comment: Have you had a chance to review this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63399128/14010152

Answer (score 0):

A `VLOOKUP` can be paired with an `IF` statement to work like this. First of all you will need a key with all the desired match-ups. And you can add a 3rd column to report if it's good or bad. Then you can have this:

[image]

You can copy & paste here to test it yourself:

```
=IF(B6 = VLOOKUP(A6,$E$4:$F$6,2,FALSE), "GOOD", "BAD")
```